# Prometheus Helm Chart: Scrape Target not detected with prometheus.io/scrape annotations

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I'm using [this prometheus chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus). In the documentation it says

> In order to get prometheus to scrape pods, you must add annotations to the the pods as below:
>
> ```
> metadata:   
>   annotations:
>     prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
>     prometheus.io/path: /metrics
>     prometheus.io/port: "8080"
> ```

So I have created a service like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-client-service
  labels:
    app: nodejs-client-app
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "5000"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nodejs-client-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
```

But my Service won't show up in the prometheus targets. What am I missing?

Comment: **...add annotations to the the pods**... By this sentence in my undestandment the annotation must be placed in the pods and not in the service. Have you tried add the annotation to your pods on deployment spec or similar?

Comment: Yes I have tried adding the annotations in my deployment file under `metadata/annotations` and `spec/template/metadata/annotations`, neither are working

Comment: Have you managed to work your way around this? I am having the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713582/target-does-not-get-scraped-by-prometheus)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem with the `stable/prometheus-operator` chart.  I tried adding the annotations above both to the pods and to the service and neither worked.

For me, the solution was to add a [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md) object.  Once added, Prometheus dynamically discovered my service:

[Fig 1: target list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shgGp.png)

[Fig 2: dynamically added scrape_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLRzq.png)

### Solution Example

This single command fixed the problem: `kubectl apply -f service-monitor.yml`

```yaml
# service-monitor.yml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    release: prom
  name: eztype
  namespace: default
spec:
  endpoints:
    - path: /actuator/prometheus
      port: management
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - default
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: eztype
```

Here, my pods and service were annotated with the name `eztype` and were exposing metrics on port 8282 under the indicated path.  For completeness here's the relavant part of my service definition:

```yaml
# service definition (partial)
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.128.156.246
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: management
    port: 8282
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8282
```

It's worth noting that ServiceMonitor objects are used in the Prometheus chart itself:

```
$ kubectl get servicemonitors -n monitor
NAME                                               AGE
prom-prometheus-operator-alertmanager              14d
prom-prometheus-operator-apiserver                 14d
prom-prometheus-operator-coredns                   14d
prom-prometheus-operator-grafana                   14d
prom-prometheus-operator-kube-controller-manager   14d
prom-prometheus-operator-kube-etcd                 14d
prom-prometheus-operator-kube-proxy                14d
prom-prometheus-operator-kube-scheduler            14d
prom-prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics        14d
prom-prometheus-operator-kubelet                   14d
prom-prometheus-operator-node-exporter             14d
prom-prometheus-operator-operator                  14d
prom-prometheus-operator-prometheus                14d
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add annotations to the the pods.
NOT service

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For use annotations for pods you need to add job 'kubernetes-pods' to prometheus scrape config  https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml#L257

example:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  honor_labels: true

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod

  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow]
      action: drop
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
      action: replace
      regex: (https?)
      target_label: __scheme__
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      regex: (.+?)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
      target_label: __address__
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
      replacement: __param_$1
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: pod
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_phase]
      regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed|Completed
      action: drop
```