# Target does not get scraped by prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

It seems that I can't get my target scraped by `prometheus` neither via the annotation method nor the `ServiceMonitor` workaround.

Here is the `spec` scetion of my `Service` Object exposing the metrics

```
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.107.228.89
  ports:
  - name: metricsport
    port: 8282
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8282
  selector:
    app: my-app
    release: my-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

This **DOES** expose metrics, which I verify by `curl`ing it via another pod from within the cluster

```
curl http://my-service-metrics:8282/metrics
(...a lot of metrics)
```

Here is my `ServiceMonitor` `spec`

```
spec:
  endpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: metricsport
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - default
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
      release: my-app
```

What else should I do/try to get my metrics being scraped by `prometheus`?

(the target does not appear in my `http://prometheus/targets`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered in Slack, need to make sure the labels on the ServiceMonitor object itself match the `serviceMonitorSelector` on the Prometheus object.